# Would like to ask to how google scripts work?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, epoch

Hi im tryng to put this formula in my google sheet "=(C2 + 7/24 - DATE(1970,1,1)) * 86400000 " to convert my time to epoch time. Is it posible to add it to google script every time i open new file it automatically will convert to epoch time? Thanks!

Comment: Formula will automatically recalculate. No need for scripts. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for  script basics: Search for time triggers, If you're interested in scripting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`onOpen()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene) simple trigger to accomplish this. "Simple" because Google will setup the trigger automatically by merely having a function named `onOpen()` in your script.

You do need to define where you want the formula to be placed. Here, I'm writing it in `Sheet1!A1`.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A1').setFormula('=(C1 + 7/24 - DATE(1970,1,1)) * 86400000');
}
```

Comment: So it will automatically convert to epoch timestamp or it will fill another row? @Diego

Comment: @CoderTrainy It will place the formula `=(C1 + 7/24 - DATE(1970,1,1)) * 86400000` into cell A1

Comment: Is there a way I can loop it in my entire column of A1? Thanks bud! @Diego

Comment: @CoderTrainy Of course. Apps script allows you to define a range (`getRange()`) and set a bunch of values at once (`setValues()` and `setFormulas()`)